# Can we infer whether or not a random variable is continuous from its generating function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This question was sparked by a comment in the topic "Branching Process" of the book *Probability and random process*.
 Let $Z_{n}$ be the number of offsprings at the $n$th generation. Assume that the number of children of each individual form i.i.d. r.v. 
Let $W_{n}:=\frac{Z_{n}}{\mathbb{E}Z_{n}}$, $W = \lim W_{n}$ in distribution, $G_{n}(s)$ be the generating function of $Z_{n}$, $G(s)$ be the generating function of $Z_{0}$, $g(s)$ be the generating function of $W$, $\mu := \mathbb{E}Z_{0}$. We can deduce that $g(s) = G(g(s^{\frac{1}{\mu}}))$. The book then says that if $\mathbb{E}(Z_{1}^2) < +\infty$, then $W$ is continuous, apart from a point mass of size $\eta$ at zero ($\eta$ is the smallest non-negative solution to $s=G(s)$, which is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(Z_{n} = 0)=\mathbb{P}$(ultimate extinction)). Why can we conclude that $W$ is continuous given its generating function?

Comment: You defined $W_n$ but what is $W$? Similarly you defined $G_n$ using a quantity that doesn't depend on $n$, and then a $G$ appears later.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks for reminding me. I have edited the question.

Comment: $EZ_1^{2} \leq \infty$ is not a meaningful assumption. This result looks non-trivial. I suspect that there is a proof somewhere in the book.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I meant to say $<$. I don't think this conclusion is proved anywhere else in the book... And from the way the author puts, it seems to be pretty trivial